# Sending patch request to Django Rest Framework API with Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I need to send put request to API for which I know only the foreign key.
How am supposed to do this.

models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, unique = True)
```

serializer.py

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   class Meta:
       model = Company
       fields = ('id', 'name','user')
```

views.py

```
class Company(object):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,IsUserThenReadPatch)
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
       user = self.request.user
       return Company.objects.filter(user = user)

class CompanyDetails(Company, RetrieveUpdateAPIView, APIView):

    pass
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^company/$',views.CompanyDetails.as_view()),
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to enable all CRUD operations in DRF you probably want to use [`ViewSet`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) instead of `View`:

```
# views.py
class CompanyViewSet(ViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,IsUserThenReadPatch)
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
       user = self.request.user
       return Company.objects.filter(user = user)

# urls.py
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'company', CompanyViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

The above will allow you do send all CRUD REST requests:

- `GET /company` - list all companies
- `POST /company` - create a company
- `GET /company/:id` - get a single company
- `PUT/POST /company/:id` - update a company
- `PATCH /company/:id` - partially update a company
- `DELETE /company/:id` - delete a company

You can read more in the DRF docs - [viewsets](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) and [routers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/)